# How can I add an class to a container when a component get focus or is clicked in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I want to add a class to the container when the input field has a focus or when the dropdown component gets focus or is clicked. On unfocus the class must be removed.

The input container must get the class 'active' when the input field or the dropdownComponent has focus or is clicked. For the input field I added ng-focus and ng-blur, which works.

But `ng-focus` and `ng-blur` doesn't work on a included component. I wrap the component in a div container, but this time `ng-blur` didn't work.

The code:

```html
<div class="input-container" ng-class="{'active': focus}">
    <dropdownComponent ng-if="dropdownButton" element="dropdownElement">
    </dropdownComponent>

    <input type="text"
        id="{{inputElement.key}}"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="{{inputElement.placeholder}}"
        ng-model="inputElement.values[0]"
        ng-readonly="{{::inputElement.readonly}}"
        ng-focus="focus=true"
        ng-blur="focus=false;"
        ng-required="{{::inputElement.required}}"
        novalidate />
</div>
```

Is there an option to add something like

```html
<dropdownComponent ng-if="dropdownButton" 
                   ng-focus="focus=true"
                   ng-blur="focus=false"
                   element="dropdownElement">
</dropdownComponent>
```

Directly adding `ng-focus` and `ng-blur` to the component didn't work.

focus-within with css works, but this doesn't support older browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn’t work for the component because the `focus` and `blur` events work only for the form elements. For the component with the dropdown, you may use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. And use the `click` event when the component gets clicked.

Updated:

```
<div class="input-container" ng-class="{'active': toggleClass}">
    <dropdownComponent ng-if="dropdownButton" ng-click="toggleClass = !toggleClass" element="dropdownElement"></dropdownComponent>
</div>
```

In your .js file set the variable as `$scope.toggleClass = false;`

**REMOVE CLASS ONCLICK OUTSIDE:**

```
var element = document.querySelector('.input-container');    
$window.onclick = function(event) {
        if(event.target !== element && element.classList.contains('active')) {
            $scope.toggleClass = false; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: adding ng-click to the component didn't work. Added inside <dropdownComponent ng-click="focus-true"></dropdownComponent> 

Also directly adding the ng-click to the component didn't help.

Comment: `mouseenter` and `mouseleave ` events worked? Is that only `ng-click` not working?

Comment: mouseenter is for hovering, I need it only for clicking/focus.

Comment: I will try this, but need I bind ng click?

Comment: No just use the above method. I hope that helps

Comment: this works when I click on the button :) but I want to remove the class on clicking outside the dropdownbutton.